# Correct iptables rules for a reverse vpn set up

Tags: vpn, iptables, wireguard

I set up a VPS to be a reverse vpn to my self-hosted mailserver, and would like to know if these rules I've come up with make sense and are correct for what I'm doing.

The mailserver (mailcow docker container) sits behind nat and hosts a couple of other web apps. There is a reverse proxy (also a docker container) on the vps for the apps that sit on the vps, and another reverse proxy on the mailserver for some private access web apps. The mailserver itself is listed in the reverse proxy on the VPS.

My question is: Is this a "correct" setup as far as the firewall rules? I can get it to work with the mailserver using the explicit ip addresses in the mailserver wg0.conf... but every tutorial i've looked at has the "client" (ie- mailserver in this case) with 0.0.0.0/0, but when I try to actually use that it doesn't pass any traffic. I'm a total iptables nub, so I need some guidance from someone who knows more about it as to if I did this right or not, and if not... What to fix?

the VPS is Oracle linux 8. The mail server is Rocky linux 8. Docker is running on both hosts. Both are also running wireguard at the kernel level (not in containers).

Here is the bash script i cobbled together from various posts online for standing up the iptables rules for wireguard on the vps:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

# set up install and uninstall directives
A=-A
I=-I
if [[ "$1" == "down" ]]; then
  A=-D
  I=-D
fi

ip4_localip=10.0.0.11
ip4_wg_subnet=10.20.100
ip4_source=$ip4_wg_subnet.10
ip4_dest=$ip4_wg_subnet.11

# SET PUBLIC IP INTERFACE NAME
ni=enp0s3
# SET WIREGUARD INTERFACE NAME
wg=wg0
# SET FORWARDED PORTS
TCP_PORTS="25 110 143 465 587 993 995 4190"

# Accept it all.
# Per docker manual: iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i src_if -o dst_if -j ACCEPT
# to preserve linux routing capabilities.
# Docker requires forwards to be on its own chain, use DOCKER-USER instead of FORWARD
sudo iptables $I DOCKER-USER -i $wg -o $ni -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables $I DOCKER-USER -s $ip4_wg_subnet.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables $I DOCKER-USER -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

for p in $TCP_PORTS
do
    # Allow traffic on specified ports.
    sudo iptables $A DOCKER-USER -i $ni -o $wg -p tcp --syn --dport $p -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
    # Forward traffic from public network to wireguard on specified ports
    sudo iptables -t nat $A PREROUTING -i $ni -p tcp --dport $p -j DNAT --to-destination $ip4_dest
    # Forward traffic from wireguard back to public network on specified ports
    sudo iptables -t nat $A POSTROUTING -o $wg -p tcp --dport $p -d $ip4_dest -j SNAT --to-source $ip4_source
done

# Source nat.
sudo iptables -t nat $A POSTROUTING -s $ip4_wg_subnet.0/24 ! -d $ip4_wg_subnet.0/24 -j SNAT --to $ip4_localip

# Masquerade.
sudo iptables -t nat $A POSTROUTING -o $wg -j MASQUERADE
```

Here's my wg0.conf for the VPS:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.20.100.10/24
MTU = 1280
PrivateKey = KEY
ListenPort = 51820

PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PostUp = /etc/wireguard/scripts/vps-load-wg-iptables.sh
PostDown = /etc/wireguard/scripts/vps-load-wg-iptables.sh down
PostDown = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0

[Peer]
PublicKey = KEY
PresharedKey = KEY
AllowedIPs = 10.20.100.11/32, 10.20.1.11/32
PersistentKeepalive = 20
```

Here's the wg0.conf for the mailserver:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.20.100.11/32
MTU = 1280
PrivateKey = KEY

PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PostDown = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0

[Peer]
PublicKey = KEY
PresharedKey = KEY
AllowedIPs = 10.20.100.10/32, 10.0.0.11/32
Endpoint = VPS_PUBLIC_IP:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 20
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more further mucking around, it now works as intended.
Mail server reports correct IP now and the other web traffic to and from the proxies goes where it needs to go. Hopefully it helps someone else :)

**Updated Bash script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

# set up install and uninstall directives
A=-A
I=-I
if [[ "$1" == "down" ]]; then
  A=-D
  I=-D
fi

ip4_localip=10.0.0.11
ip4_wg_subnet=10.20.100
ip4_source=$ip4_wg_subnet.10
ip4_dest=$ip4_wg_subnet.11

# SET PUBLIC IP INTERFACE NAME
ni=enp0s3
# SET WIREGUARD INTERFACE NAME
wg=wg0
# SET FORWARDED PORTS
TCP_PORTS="25 110 143 465 587 993 995 4190"

# Accept it all.
# Per docker manual, Docker requires forwards to be on its chain
# use DOCKER-USER instead of FORWARD
sudo iptables $I DOCKER-USER -s $ip4_wg_subnet.0/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables $I DOCKER-USER -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# Source nat.
sudo iptables -t nat $A POSTROUTING -s $ip4_wg_subnet.0/24 ! -d $ip4_wg_subnet.0/24 -j SNAT --to $ip4_localip
# Masquerade.
sudo iptables -t nat $A POSTROUTING -o $wg -j MASQUERADE

for p in $TCP_PORTS
do
    # Allow traffic on specified ports.
    sudo iptables $A DOCKER-USER -i $ni -o $wg -p tcp --syn --dport $p -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
    # Forward traffic from public network to wireguard on specified ports
    sudo iptables -t nat $A PREROUTING -i $ni -p tcp --dport $p -j DNAT --to-destination $ip4_dest
    # Forward traffic from wireguard back to public network on specified ports
    sudo iptables -t nat $A POSTROUTING -o $wg -p tcp --dport $p -d $ip4_dest -j SNAT --to-source $ip4_source
done
```

**Updated wg0.conf for VPS: edit:** the real local ip of the mail server doesn't need to be in the vps wg0.conf; the routing allows the use of >only< the wireguard ip range from the vps. use the mail server's wireguard ip as the target for the host entries in the vps proxy that send things to the mail server over http..

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.20.100.10/24
MTU = 1280
PrivateKey = KEY
ListenPort = 51820

PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PostUp = /etc/wireguard/scripts/vps-load-wg-iptables.sh
PostDown = /etc/wireguard/scripts/vps-load-wg-iptables.sh down
PostDown = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0

[Peer]
PublicKey = KEY
PresharedKey = KEY
AllowedIPs = 10.20.100.11/32
PersistentKeepalive = 20
```

**Updated wg0.conf for mail server:**

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.20.100.11/24
MTU = 1280
PrivateKey = KEY

PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PostDown = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0

[Peer]
PublicKey = KEY
PresharedKey = KEY
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = VPS_PUBLIC_IP:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 20
```