# Stuck on converting firewalld direct rule syntax to rich rule syntax

Tags: vpn, wireguard, firewalld

I've been googling around to try to translate an iptables script I use for some wireguard rules into native firewalld rules, since all the docs I've been reading about iptables indicate that:

- iptables is deprecated (and has been for some time) and the rules
  do not persist across reboots without re-inserting them every boot or during runtime with a bash script.
- nftables won't persist either if firewalld is in use
- ephemeral rules aren't really all that fun to begin with either way.

In my reading it seems that firewalld 0.9.3 might have the functionality to do the things iptables (aka direct rules) do, but the documentation found on google searches seems to be contradictory or too terse for me to wrap my head around. Since I want to use firewalld natively, the direct rules in the below script need to be converted into rich rules, but I don't know how to get that done since most tutorials are not even using the newer methods yet.

The iptables script I'm converting from is [here](https://superuser.com/a/1762045/1762005).
Below is the working bash script I came up with to do it in native firewalld syntax; The thing I'm stuck on is the direct rules. **How do I convert the 3 direct rules below into native rich rules?**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

# set up install and uninstall directives
ADDREMOVE='--add'
if [[ "$1" == "down" ]]; then
  ADDREMOVE='--remove'
fi

# Public wireguard port
wg_listen_port=51820
# SET WIREGUARD INTERFACE NAME
wg=wg0
# Local private ip
ip4_localip=10.0.0.11
# SET PUBLIC IP INTERFACE NAME
ni=enp0s3
# wireguard subnet vars
ip4_wg_subnet=10.20.100
ip4_wg_source=$ip4_wg_subnet.10
ip4_wg_dest=$ip4_wg_subnet.11

# Add service ports to public zone
PUBLICSERVICES='http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps smtp-submission docker-registry'
for ENUM in $PUBLICSERVICES
do
    sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public $ADDREMOVE-service="$ENUM"
    sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public $ADDREMOVE-service="$ENUM"
done

# Set wireguard public zone listen port
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public $ADDREMOVE-port=$wg_listen_port/udp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public $ADDREMOVE-port=$wg_listen_port/udp

# Enable masquerade on the public zone
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public $ADDREMOVE-masquerade
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public $ADDREMOVE-masquerade

# Add the wireguard interface to the trusted zone
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted $ADDREMOVE-interface=$wg
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted $ADDREMOVE-interface=$wg

# Add the wireguard subnet as a trusted zone source
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted $ADDREMOVE-source=$ip4_wg_subnet.0/24
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted $ADDREMOVE-source=$ip4_wg_subnet.0/24

# Enable masquerade on the trusted zone
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted $ADDREMOVE-masquerade
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted $ADDREMOVE-masquerade

# Set the wireguard source and destination SNAT target to the host ip
sudo firewall-cmd --direct $ADDREMOVE-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -s $ip4_wg_subnet.0/24 ! -d $ip4_wg_subnet.0/24 -j SNAT --to "$ip4_localip"
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct $ADDREMOVE-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -s $ip4_wg_subnet.0/24 ! -d $ip4_wg_subnet.0/24 -j SNAT --to "$ip4_localip"

# Mail services forwarding rules
FORWARD_PORTS="25 110 143 465 587 993 995 4190"
for ENUM in $FORWARD_PORTS
do
    # Allow host traffic to specified ports on the wireguard subnet.
    sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted $ADDREMOVE-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address='$ip4_localip'/32 destination address='$ip4_wg_subnet'.0/24 port port='$ENUM' protocol=tcp accept'
    sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted $ADDREMOVE-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address='$ip4_localip'/32 destination address='$ip4_wg_subnet'.0/24 port port='$ENUM' protocol=tcp accept'
    
    # Forward traffic from public interface to destination address on specified ports
    sudo firewall-cmd --direct $ADDREMOVE-rule ipv4 nat PREROUTING 0 -i $ni -p tcp --dport $ENUM -j DNAT --to-destination $ip4_wg_dest
    sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct $ADDREMOVE-rule ipv4 nat PREROUTING 0 -i $ni -p tcp --dport $ENUM -j DNAT --to-destination $ip4_wg_dest
    
    # Forward traffic from wireguard interface to source address on specified ports
    sudo firewall-cmd --direct $ADDREMOVE-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -o $wg -p tcp --dport $ENUM -d $ip4_wg_dest -j SNAT --to-source $ip4_wg_source
    sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct $ADDREMOVE-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -o $wg -p tcp --dport $ENUM -d $ip4_wg_dest -j SNAT --to-source $ip4_wg_source
done
```